# pydot.InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found

Tags: 16.04, server, python, python3

I couldn't find any solution that is related to Ubuntu server.
I am going to use `plot_model` `from keras.utils import plot_model` to save the *.png* format of the model. However, the error occurs saying `GraphViz's executables not found. Full trace-back is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/00_files/project/combined/kfold_loop.py", line 85, in <module>
    plot_model(combined_net(), to_file = 'kfold_loop.png')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/utils/vis_utils.py", line 133, in plot_model
    dot = model_to_dot(model, show_shapes, show_layer_names, rankdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/utils/vis_utils.py", line 55, in model_to_dot
    _check_pydot()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/utils/vis_utils.py", line 26, in _check_pydot
    pydot.Dot.create(pydot.Dot())
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydot/__init__.py", line 1951, in create
    'GraphViz\'s executables not found' )
pydot.InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have *0.13.2* version of `graphviz` and *1.4.1* version of `pydot`on Ubuntu 16.04 server.

What else should be done?

FYI: I am accessing Ubuntu server via PyCharm on Windows 10.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dot -v` on the server

Comment: `The program 'dot' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install graphviz`

Comment: Well i think that's the problem, try installing graphviz using `sudo apt install graphviz`

Comment: `graphviz` is already installed offline, because I don't have `sudo` privilege

Comment: Can you tell me how exactly do you install graphviz on the server?

Comment: after downloading a `.whl` file to the directory, just `pip install graphviz-0.13.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl --user`

Comment: Both `graphviz` and `pydot` package are the same thing. They are python binding for graphviz. To use them you also need to install graphviz (the app). If you doesn't have access to sudo, you need to compile graphviz manually and add the compiled binary to PATH

Comment: could you guide me step by step?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you are mistaking the python graphviz package (https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/) with the graphviz app (https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/). In order to use `pydot` or `graphviz` (the python package) you need a working copy of graphviz (the app).

If you doesn't have access to sudo, there are two ways that i could think of

1. Use conda (recommended)
2. Compile graphviz manually

However in order to compile graphviz manually without `sudo` access is really hard because of the many dependencies required. Because of that, I recommend you to use conda.

Conda step by step:

- Download miniconda (https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)
- Install miniconda by running the downloaded script
- Create a new environment `conda create -n env_name python=3.5`
- Install graphviz (the app) `conda install -n env_name graphviz`
- Activate the conda environment `conda activate env_name`
- Install your other python dependencies using pip

**edit**

For installing conda environment on an offline machine, you can install conda env locally on your dev machine and then move it to the server using conda pack

- Install the environment locally (on a similar operating system)
- Install conda pack on the local machine `pip install conda-pack`
- Package the environment `conda pack -n env_name`
- Copy the created `env_name.tar.gz` to the server
- Extract the archive to a new folder (e.g. env_name)
- To activate the environment run `source env_name/bin/activate`

Comment: Even if I create a conda env, I can only manually download and then install from local directory, because I'm behind a security firewall, have no access to cloud based sites (github, gitlab, etc). Therefore, I'd rather get instructions on how to install locally. Thanks!

Comment: Again, I can't use `pip install package_name` because `pip` searches a package name from a cloud sites which I don't have access to. I don't need any conda env since I am not going to use it. I just need to find a suitable **graphviz app** that you mentioned earlier and install it on my Ubuntu server manually. For instance, on Windows I can download graphviz app and place it in my _C://_ disk and arrange the path in Environmental variables, but on Ubuntu I have no idea of how to accomplish this.